# isBlank method to test string without space StringUtils.isBlank(" ") = false;

Tags: java, java-8, string-utils

Hi I found this method is `StringUtils.isBlank()` 
I'm using JDK 1.8.51 I'm not able to found it there is any jar to download to have it?

thanks

Comment: Something like: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Comment: Spring also has the same impl: `org.springframework.util.StringUtils.isEmpty()`. If you're using spring, you get this for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`StringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) class is from Apache Commons lang. The latest version is available from Maven Central. You can [download it here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.7).